# Get MongoDB Databases in a JavaScript Array?

Tags: mongodb

I know that in the MongoDB terminal, I can run `show dbs` to see the available databases. I want to list the databases in a programmatic way so that I can iterate over them and delete some based upon a regular expression.

I have tried `db.runCommand("show dbs")` but does not return results to iterate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based upon this answer http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/9b3568f3a3cf4271, I was able to code up a solution.

```
use admin
dbs = db.runCommand({listDatabases: 1})
dbNames = []
for (var i in dbs.databases) { dbNames.push(dbs.databases[i].name) }
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 17):

**Iterate over MongoDB database names:**

```
> db.getMongo().getDBNames()
[
    "test",
    "admin",
    "local"
]
> db.getMongo().getDBNames
function () {
    return this.getDBs().databases.map(function (z) {return z.name;});
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The below will create an array of the names of the database:

```
var connection = new Mongo();
var dbNames = connection.getDBNames();
```